# With using login(request, user) function with a database other than default - Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

With using login(request, user) function with a database other than default - Django?

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
login(request, user)
```

Is there any possibility

> The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The
>   user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),},
    'mw': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '01_sistema',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I created a route and it works perfectly with queries. but with the function login(request, user) does not work.

```
class TenantRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return get_thread_local('using_db', 'default')

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return get_thread_local('using_db', 'default')

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return True
```

Middliware

```
def Multidb(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        try:
            usuario = request.user
            empresa = usuario.empresa
            print('0')
        except:
            empresa = request.GET['empresa']
            print('1')

        @thread_local(using_db=empresa)
        def execute_request(request):
            return get_response(request)
        response = execute_request(request)
        return response
    return middleware
```

The whole problem is that the login section is not registered because of the error in the login(request, user)

thank you all for your attention.

Comment: Remove the `'default'` database, since that one does *not* contain an `'ENGINE'`.

Comment: django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection default doesn't exist

Comment: What if you rename '`mw'` to `'default'`?

Comment: The idea is to use multiple databases.

Comment: 'mw', 'db_1','db_2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def tenant_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        host = request.get_host().split(':')[0]
        subdomain = host.split('.')[0]

        response = get_response(request)
        return response
    return middleware


def multidb_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        host = request.get_host().split(':')[0]
        subdomain = host.split('.')[0]

        @thread_local(using_db=subdomain)
        def execute_request(request):
            return get_response(request)

        response = execute_request(request)
        return response
    return middleware
```